# c++: Declare function inside of function call

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Is it possible to pass a function definition as an arguement and if so what is the syntax for that? If it is not, what would be the reason? I would like to do something like:

```
double arr1[10], arr2[10];

std::equal(arr1, &(arr1[5]), arr2, (bool(*)(double a, double b){return a == -b;});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lambdas for that:

```
std::equal(arr1, arr1 + 5, arr2, [](double a, double b) { return a == -b; });
```

Comment: I think you should mention it's a C++11 feature.

Comment: @Jueecy: I think the OP should mention if she wants a solution for an older version of the language :-)

Comment: That is cool, thanks, but you are right I should have mentioned that I was interessted in a solution that does not involve c++11. :)